# Pandas: Drop all rows that are contained in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to eliminate all rows from a pandas DataFrame whose entry in the column 'Beguenstigter/Zahlungspflichtiger' is contained in a list (or a set). `amazon` here is just a list of strings.

My best effort after researching on this site is this:

```
extract_df = extract_df.drop(extract_df[extract_df['Beguenstigter/Zahlungspflichtiger'] in amazon].index)

print(extract_df)
```

but not only is it chunky and unaesthetic it also throws errors:

If I make amazon a set I get

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

If I keep it as a list I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can someone explain to me why this command is producing these errors and what the correct command would be? Many of the posts I have seen on the topic here seem to be already deprecated and no solution has worked so far. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (`Alt + 126` for the `~`, it stands for the logic negation while subsetting)
`extract_df[~extract_df['Beguenstigter/Zahlungspflichtiger'].isin(amazon)]`